# Remove Junk characters with Informatica Cloud

Tags: salesforce, character, cloud, informatica

I use Informatica Cloud, and on a mapping, need to connect to a SalesForce Object.
One of field contains junk character (Ã, ...). 
When open target file with Notepadd++, I see it consider this character as 'NUL' (in black). When I perform a search, with Regular expression, it found those character when searching '\x00'

So, I try a REPLACESTR(1,field,NULL,''), REG_REPLACE(field,'\x00',''), but it still appear and cause error when use this file as source on another mapping.

Is there a way to remove all this kind of junk characters?

Of course, I try too to copy / paste this character on an utf8 file, put an ASCII(field) to output, and use a replacestr(1, field, CHR(XX),''), but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have struggled with this for some time, usually I've found that there are multiple different special characters in the file which are all prepended by \x00.

One strategy would be to feed the records into an xml transformation at which point these characters will be converted to their text representations and then to remove them.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. It seems I've not the XML Transformation enable in Informatica Cloud.. :( And, I've not the hand of managing component. So do you think there is another walkthrough ? Regards

Comment: Finally, I think to found a solution. Just extract the 'NUL' value and apply a ASCII on expression transformation. So I put a replacestr with this ascii code, and seems cleaning the value. Thanks to you. Regards